# Transforming dataframe to track the changes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have some students data and the subjects they have elected.

```
id     name   date from  date to    Subjectname  note
1188    Cera  01-08-2016 30-09-2016 math         approved
1188    Cera  01-10-2016            elec    
1199    ron   01-06-2017            english      app-true
1288    Snow  01-01-2017            tally   
1433    sansa 25-01-2016 14-07-2016 tally   
1433    sansa 15-07-2016 16-01-2017 tally        relected
1844    amy   01-10-2016 10-11-2017 adv 
1522    stark 01-01-2016            phy 
1722    sid   01-06-2017 31-03-2018 history 
1722    sid   01-04-2018            history      as per request
1844    amy   01-01-2016 30-09-2016 science 
2100    arya  01-08-2016 30-09-2016 english 
2100    arya  01-10-2016 31-05-2017 math         taken
2100    arya  01-06-2017            english
```

I am looking for outpur like:

```
id      name    from        to          subject from subject to
1188    Cera    01-08-2016  01-10-2016  math         elec
1199    ron     01-06-2017              english 
1288    Snow    01-01-2017              tally   
1433    sansa   25-01-2016  16-01-2017  tally        tally
1522    stark   01-01-2016              phy 
1722    sid     01-06-2017  01-04-2018  history      history
1844    amy     01-01-2016  10-11-2017  science      adv
2100    arya    01-08-2016  31-05-2017  english      math
2100    arya    01-06-2017              math         english
```

column 'from' has the minimum date value corresponding to the name.
column 'to' has the maximum date value corresponding to the name.
column 'subject from' has the 'Subjectname' value corresponding to the column 'from' and 'name'.
column 'subject to' has the 'Subjectname' value corresponding to the column 'to' and 'name'.

i need to track the transaction made by student and the subjectname they changed (subject from and subject to).
Please let me know how to achieve this.

or please let me know if there is an easy way to get the an output which contains transaction details per student and the subject they changed.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) by column `Subjectname`, so is possible use [`idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin.html) and 
[`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) for subject by minimal and maximal datetimes per groups:

```
df['date from'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date from'])
df['date to'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date to'])

d = {'date from':['min', 'idxmin'], 'date to':['max', 'idxmax']}
df1 = df.set_index('Subjectname').groupby(['id','name']).agg(d)
df1.columns = df1.columns.map('_'.join)
d1 = {'date from_min':'from','date to_max':'to',
      'date from_idxmin':'subject from','date to_idxmax':'subject to'}

cols = ['from','to','subject from','subject to']
df1 = df1.rename(columns=d1).reindex(columns=cols).reset_index()
print (df1)
     id   name       from         to subject from subject to
0  1188   Cera 2016-01-08 2016-09-30         math       math
1  1199    ron 2017-01-06        NaT      english        NaN
2  1288   Snow 2017-01-01        NaT        tally        NaN
3  1433  sansa 2016-01-25 2017-01-16        tally      tally
4  1522  stark 2016-01-01        NaT          phy        NaN
5  1722    sid 2017-01-06 2018-03-31      history    history
6  1844    amy 2016-01-01 2017-10-11      science        adv
7  2100   arya 2016-01-08 2017-05-31      english       math
```

Comment: thanks a lot.. it worked. but one transaction for arya is not coming 2100 arya 01-06-2017  math english

Comment: @aim - hmmm, why is for `arya` 2 lines in output? And for `sansa` only one row? Also why is `to` column in your output different like me? Can you explain more?

Comment: @jezreal - arya had 2 transaction, she changed from english to math and then again from math to english. whereas sansa changed from tally to tally, so only one row for her. regarding dates: to column corresponds to 2nd transaction's max date. for Cera  01-08-2016 30-09-2016 math and Cera  01-10-2016            elec. so from - 01-08-2016 and to - 01-10-2016 and subject from is math and subject to is elec

Answer (score 0):

my df from your first 3 rows, it should be ok to demo how to do this.
df:

```
     id  name  date_from     date_to subject_name      note
0  1188  Cera 2016-01-08  30-09-2016         math  approved
1  1188  Cera 2016-01-10                     elec
2  1199   ron 2017-01-06                  english  app-true
```

just paste code here.

```
# make date from and date to to one column to get max and min date
df1 = df[['id', 'name', 'date_from', 'subject_name', 'note']]
df2 = df[['id', 'name', 'date_to', 'subject_name', 'note']]
df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2])

df1.columns = ['id', 'name', 'date', 'subject_name', 'note']
df2.columns = ['id', 'name', 'date', 'subject_name', 'note']
df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2])
df3['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df3['date'])
df3 = df3.dropna()
df3:
     id  name       date subject_name      note
0  1188  Cera 2016-01-08         math  approved
1  1188  Cera 2016-01-10         elec
2  1199   ron 2017-01-06      english  app-true
0  1188  Cera 2016-09-30         math  approved
#here you get from and to date for each name
df4 = df3.groupby('name').agg({'date':[max,min]})
df4.columns = ['to','from']
df4 = df4.reset_index()
df4:
   name         to       from
0  Cera 2016-09-30 2016-01-08
1   ron 2017-01-06 2017-01-06
# match "name" and "to" in df4 with "name" and "date" in df3, you got the earliest subject and latest 
df_sub_from = pd.merge(df4,df3,how='left',left_on=['name','to'],right_on=['name','date'])
df_sub_from
df_sub_to = pd.merge(df4,df3,how='left',left_on=['name','to'],right_on=['name','date'])
df_sub_from = pd.merge(df4,df3,how='left',left_on=['name','from'],right_on=['name','date'])
#remove unneed columns
df_sub_from = df_sub_from[['id','name','from','to','subject_name']]
df_sub_to = df_sub_to[['id','name','from','to','subject_name']]
# merge together and rename nicely
df_final = pd.merge(df_sub_from,df_sub_to,left_on=['id','name','from','to'],right_on=['id','name','from','to'])
df_final.columns = ['id','name','from','to','subject_from','subject_to']
```

here it is:

```
     id  name       from         to subject_from subject_to
0  1188  Cera 2016-01-08 2016-09-30         math       math
1  1199   ron 2017-01-06 2017-01-06      english    english
```